# how to hiding the textview text

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout

In layout, `TextView` would be created but behind the `TextView` there should be some words are behind. How should I identify?

This is android studio latest version

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/roomnum"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="2dp"
        android:textColor="@color/colorBlack"
        android:textSize="@dimen/activity_title" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/roomtype"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="2dp"
        android:textColor="@color/color_graylight"
        android:textSize="@dimen/activity_title" />

</LinearLayout>
```

I want behind the words.

Comment: Your question is not very clear. Please [edit] it to better explain exactly what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

Use `RelativeLayout` to place two texts on top of each other. Then toggle their `visibility` accordingly.
For example when `button` is clicked:

```
textViewFirst.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE)
textViewSecond.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE)
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems the question is not very clear. I have sample code here that can help you.

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <!--<RelativeLayout-->
        <!--android:layout_width="wrap_content"-->
        <!--android:layout_height="wrap_content">-->
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:text="A"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textColor="#000"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:text="SAMPLE TWO"
        android:textSize="10sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
    <!--</RelativeLayout>-->

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

**Sample screenshot**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I have a strange feeling that your question is asking about a hint. For example:
You have a TextView and expected input is some room in a house. So the TextView will show something like "Room name", it will be in the color of light gray. If somebody types into the TextView text color will be black with his input. Am I right?

**EDIT:**
After your comment I am sure you are talking about Hint. There is no reson for hint in TextView it is used in EditText to let user know what is the expected input there.

```
<EditText
        android:id="@+id/text_New_Name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="HERE IS YOUR HINT"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

Comment: No..In textview,there should be no text appears but in the output it show the text?how would be possible?but this should be the xml